# Linux headless server..want to know if was shutdown correctly

Tags: linux

Simple question.

I have a Linux server headless,no keyboard,no screen

I connect it using ssh

The question is: is possible to know if server was

shutdown not gracefully(for example,reset button or power outage)?

Fs is btrfs and distro is debian 9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `/var/log/syslog`.

The command `/sbin/reboot` logs a bunch of "Stopping" entries followed by an `rsyslogd` entry dated from the last boot:

```
Nov 15 07:36:03 myhost rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="890" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] **rsyslogd was HUPed**
```

and rsyslogd exiting with:

```
Nov 16 00:23:56 myhost rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="890" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] **exiting on signal 15**.
```

30-ish seconds later the syslog entry for the boot starts with

```
Nov 16 00:24:27 myhost rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="947" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] **start**
```

If you have a rsyslogd start without something like a preceding HUP, the system probably lost power rather than was shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Another good line if you must find if shutdown is called and system

make clean shutdown

```
Jan 12 07:36:39 nas init: Switching to runlevel: 0
```

is on /var/log/messages